# How to load blob data or original file content using ngx-doc viewer in angular 9?

Tags: angular9, documentviewer, ngx-doc-viewer

Actually I want to load my **blob data** or **original file content** in **ngx-doc-viewer**,

I could not see any solutions here to load the **blob** or **file content** in **ngx-doc-viewer**

**It requires file path**

But **Instead of using file path we need to load  blob data or file original content**

Below I mentioned the code

```
<ngx-doc-viewer #document_viewer [url]="fileURL" viewer="google" style="width:100%;height:93vh;">
 </ngx-doc-viewer>
```

Instead of using **[url]="fileURL"**. We want to load blob data
**let BlobData = "blob text";**

Comment: please put your code here what you tried before

Comment: I have added sample code in question @KiranMistry

Comment: Try viewer="url". This works for me !